# having some trouble getting two divs to float next to each other

Tags: html, css, layout

I know this issue has been answered over and over again, but I can't find something that works for me. I think it has something to do with a lack of display: attribute in content or sidebar but I'm not sure what. Please take a look at my code and see if you can spot my error.

I apologize for asking this question, that I'm sure has some obvious answer but I havent been able to spot it.

Thanks in advance

Andy

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Andy's test website</title>

<style type="text/css">
html, body
{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

p
{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

#container
{
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:white;
  width:760px;
  border:1px solid gray;
}
#header
{
  line-height:130%;
  border-bottom:1px solid gray;
  width:760px;
}
#content
{
  float: left;
  width:500px;
  margin-right:260px;
}
#sidebar
{
  float: right;
  width:260px;
}
#footer
{
  clear:both;
  width:760px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

  <div id="header">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="content">

    <p>
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod 
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </p>

  </div>

  <div id='sidebar'>
    <p>
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
      magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,"
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this CSS

```
  #content
  {
    float: left;
    width:480px;
    margin-right:20px;
  }
  #sidebar
  {
    float: left;
    width:260px;
  }
```

Both elements should float left and the first one will have a margin right.

Comment: Excellent it worked. Can you explain why both elements should float left? and what is going on in your code that my code wasn't doing. Again thanks for the answer.

Comment: because if you float left both, they will be next to each other, like side by side with the correct width (not greater than the size of the parent div). If you have float right and float left you can have the result you want but I think it's easier with my solution

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your use of `margin` on `#content`.  With a margin of 260px, the outer width of `#content` becomes 760px, which is the entire available inner width of the parent `#container`.  In the page flow, you see your `#sidebar` below your `#content` because there simply isn't enough room for the two elements to exist side by side.

Drop `margin-right` from `#content` and things should display as you want them.

Keep in mind that this configuration is very tight and will break again when you introduce any CSS properties that alter the outer width of either `#content` or `#sidebar` (this includes `border`, `padding`, and `margin`.  Reading about the [CSS box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) will help you better understand what is going on.